# Search part from different rows and sum values of RUN_TIME column and set the value to a specific row

Tags: sql

I have this table example:

```
PART   RUN_TIME
A         5
B         3
C         2
D         4
E         5
```

And I want to sum the RUN_TIME of 'D' to the RUN_TIME of 'A'.

This is how it is supposed to look*.

```
PART   RUN_TIME
A         9*
B         3
C         2
D         4
E         5
```

Comment: YOUR SHIFT KEY IS BROKEN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the table, it'll probably look like

```
update tbl
set run_time = run_time + (select run_time from tbl where part = 'D')
where part = 'A';
```

This assumes that part is unique in your table.
It also depends on the SQL dialect your system uses.

Answer (score 0):

Using subquery (only if part is `UNIQUE`):

```
SELECT part,
   CASE WHEN part='A' 
       THEN run_time + (SELECT run_time FROM tbl WHERE part = 'D') 
       ELSE run_time END AS run_time
FROM tbl;
```